# Quiero conectarme a mi BD y que solo me acepte archivos .csv ¿En que estoy mal?

Tags: php, pdo

Buenas colegas tengo un error en mi código donde intento conectarme a mi BD con la extensión PDO para mas seguridad pero soy nuevo utilizándolo (usaba mas *mysqli_connect*). Y también me marca errores en mi sentencia donde quiero que solo me acepte archivos tipo CSV.

Este es mi código **`entregablepanel.php`**:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

</head>

    <body>
    <div class="container mt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="file" class="btn btn-primary" name="archivo" accept=".csv"> 
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="subir"> <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> </button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <?php
                if (!isset($_REQUEST['subir'])) {
                    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
                    $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];

                    if (!((strpos($tipo = "text/csv") || strpos($tipo, "csv")))){
                        echo "Archivo no valido"; 
                    }
                        else{
                            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],  $nombre)){
                                echo "El archivo ha sido cargado correctamente.";
                            }
                            else{
                                   echo "Ocurrió algún error al subir el fichero. No pudo guardarse.";
                            }
                        }
                        
                    $destino = "csv/$nombre";
                    $res = copy($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $destino);
                ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $res ? "primary" : "danger"; ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <?php echo $res ? "Archivo subido exitosamente" : "Error al subir archivo"; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php

                if( file_exists($destino)==true ){
                    include_once "conexion.php";
                        $archivo = fopen($destino, "r");
                        $query = $pdo->prepare ("INSERT INTO entregable_facturacion
                        (Nombre_Entregable_Fact, Periodicidad_Entre_Fact, Salario_Entre_Fact, Fiscal_Entre_Fact, No_Fiscal_Entre_Fact, Dispersion_Entre_Fact, ISR_RET_Entre_Fact, Faltas_Entre_Fact, Horas_Extra_Entre_Fact, Banco_Entre_Fact, Tarjeta_Entre_Fact, Cuenta_Entre_Fact, Observaciones_Entre_Fact) values ");
                        $i=0;

                    while( ($columna=fgetcsv($archivo))!=false ){
                        if($i>0){
                            $query=$query."('" .$columna[1]. "','" .$columna[2]. "','" .$columna[3]. "','" .$columna[4]. "','" .$columna[5]. "','" .$columna[6]. "','" .$columna[7]. "','" .$columna[8]. "','" .$columna[9]. "','" .$columna[10]. "','" .$columna[11]. "','" .$columna[12]. "','" .$columna[13]. "','" .$columna[14]. "'),";
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }

                    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
                        echo $query;
                        $resultado = prepare ($pdo, $query);

                ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $resultado ? "primary" : "danger"; ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <?php echo $resultado ? "Importacion exitosa" : "Error " . prepare ($pdo); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
            }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Y este es el código de mi **`conexión.php`**:

```
<?php
$pdo= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bdgmg','root','');
```

Ya revise varias veces las líneas donde me marcan los errores pero... no encuentro la lógica, les comparto las imágenes de los errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pensé que solo era por el posicionamiento de mis llaves pero ya las cambie y me marca los mismos errores, cualquier ayuda se los agradecería mucho por favor :D

Comment: Los mensajes de error van como texto por favor

Comment: Solo tenes que sacar el `!` en `if (!isset($_REQUEST['subir'])) {`, estas negando la condición. PD: creo que seria correcto usar `$_POST['subir']` en lugar de `$_REQUEST['subir']`

Answer (score 0):

primero que nada necesitas separar el problema en partes. Yo sugeriria esto

1. Validar que la conexión al SQL anda bien. Esto se puede hacer haciendo un select 1 o `select version()` Por ejemplo usando este codigo

```html
<?php
    $pdo= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bdgmg','root','');
    if (!$pdo) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "Connected Successfully.";
?>
```

2. Una vez hecho el 1, ejecutar la query con valores hardcoded en lugar del loop del while insertar algunos valores dummies para validar la estructura del insert
3. Validar con un CSV de 1 linea con los valores dummie del paso anterior
4. Validar con varias lineas

Dicho esto, creo que tu problema es que no existe un csv en la carpeta a la que estas yendo

Answer (score 0):

Hice algunos cambios que me sugirieron pero aun no puedo hacer que cuando suba algún archivo solo me acepte .csv y en la conexión a la BD no entiendo muy bien como funciona la extensión PDO

Estos son los cambios que hice en el codigo `entregablepanel.php`;

```
<body>
<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" class="btn btn-primary" name="archivo" accept=".csv"> 
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="subir"> <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> </button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <?php
            if (isset($_REQUEST['subir'])) {
                $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
                $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];

                if ($tipo!= "text/csv") die ("Archivo no valido");
                $destino = "csv/$nombre";
                $res = copy($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $destino);
            ?>
                <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $res ? "primary" : "danger"; ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <?php echo $res ? "Archivo subido exitosamente" : "Error al subir archivo"; ?>
                </div>
            <?php

            if( file_exists($destino)==true ){
                include_once "conexion.php";
                    $archivo = fopen($destino, "r");
                    $query = "INSERT INTO entregable_facturacion
                    (Nombre_Entregable_Fact, Periodicidad_Entre_Fact, Salario_Entre_Fact, Fiscal_Entre_Fact, No_Fiscal_Entre_Fact, Dispersion_Entre_Fact, ISR_RET_Entre_Fact, Faltas_Entre_Fact, Horas_Extra_Entre_Fact, Banco_Entre_Fact, Tarjeta_Entre_Fact, Cuenta_Entre_Fact, Observaciones_Entre_Fact) values ";
                    $i=0;

                while( ($columna=fgetcsv($archivo))!=false ){
                    if($i>0){
                        $query=$query."('" .$columna[1]. "','" .$columna[2]. "','" .$columna[3]. "','" .$columna[4]. "','" .$columna[5]. "','" .$columna[6]. "','" .$columna[7]. "','" .$columna[8]. "','" .$columna[9]. "','" .$columna[10]. "','" .$columna[11]. "','" .$columna[12]. "','" .$columna[13]. "','" .$columna[14]. "'),";
                    }
                    $i++;
                }

                $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
                    echo $query;
                    $resultado = ($pdo, $query);

            ?>
                <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $resultado ? "primary" : "danger"; ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <?php echo $resultado ? "Importacion exitosa" : "Error " .($pdo); ?>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            }  
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En el `if ($tipo!= "text/csv") die ("Archivo no valido");` estoy diciendo que si no es un archivo CSV me lo quite o elimine (al menos en mi lógica) pero por alguna razón cuando subo el archivo correspondiente me arroja el mensaje de "Archivo no valido"

Y en el `if( file_exists($destino)==true )` donde incluyo la conexión de mi BD me sigue marcando algunos errores (PDO aun no le entiendo del todo, no se como debería ser su sintaxis)